# Joi schema validation: Joi.object define valid keys from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I  have a Joi schema like this:

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({ filter: Joi.object({ }) })
```

Then I have all valid keys for filter-object in a separate array called validKeys.

I would like to reference validKeys with filter-object. Otherwise I would have to hard code the allowed values like this:

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({ filter: Joi.object({ allowed1:Joi.string(), allowed2: Joi.string(), ... }) })
```

which I don't want to do. Is  this possible with Joi or some other Javascript tools?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your `validkeys` array looks like, but you if you set up your filter schema first and then your final schema, you can iterate through your keys and add them to your filter schema dynamically (assuming they're all supposed to be strings).

```
const joi = require('joi');

// not sure what valid key structure is like..
const validkeys = ['allowed1', 'allowed2', 'allowed3'];

// set up filter schema first.
let filterschema = {};

for (let i = 0; i < validkeys.length; i++) {
    filterschema[validkeys[i]] = joi.string();
}

// set up the final schema
let finalschema = joi.object().keys({
    filter: filterschema
});

// test
let testobj = {
    filter: {
        allowed1: 'cuthbert',
        allowed2: 'susan',
        allowed5: 'jake' // should NOT be allowed.
    }
};

let result = joi.validate(testobj, finalschema);

// should fail because key allowed5 isn't defined in filter schema.
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do that:

```js
{
  filter: Joi.object().unknown(false).required().keys(['allowed1', 'allowed2', 'allowed3'].reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val] = Joi.any()

    return acc
  }, {}))
}
```